# Как убрать ссылку в компоненте для джумлы?

Tags: joomla, php, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Установила комментарии для джумлы, все устраивает, только хотелось бы убрать ссылку-копирайт (т. к. она получается сквозная на всех страницах). Никак не могу найти, в каком файле и где это убирается, я ее скрыла через display:none, но хотелось бы убрать совсем, вот код комментериев:

```
<div id="comment-wrapper"></div>
            <script
    src='http://nastroike.com/components/com_joocomments/assets/js/showdown.js'
    type='text/javascript'></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
            //<![CDATA[
            // version 1.0.4
            var currentLanguage='ru-RU';
            var arr=Locale.list().toString();
            var tempUrl='';
            var waitTitle='Please wait...';
            var waitMessage='...While I steal your wallet';

           // check if current language is already available in Locale
           if(arr.indexOf(currentLanguage)==-1){
               Locale.define('ru-RU', 'FormValidator', {required: 'This field is required.',email: 'Please enter a valid email address. For example: fred@domain.com.',errorPrefix: 'Error: '});           }        
            Locale.use('ru-RU');
            var article_id="142";
            var urlCurrentPage=window.location;
            var valCU=urlCurrentPage.toString().indexOf("://www.", 0);
            tempUrl = "http://nastroike.com/index.php?option=com_joocomments";
            var valTU=tempUrl.toString().indexOf("://www.",0);
            if((valCU==4 || valCU==5) && valTU <4 ){tempUrl=tempUrl.replace("://","://www.");}
            if(valCU<4 && (valTU==4 || valTU==5)){tempUrl=tempUrl.replace("://www.","://");}
            var paImg='';
            window.addEvent("load", function() {
                initialize(tempUrl);
                paImg='http://nastroike.com/components/com_joocomments/assets/img/';
                var myImages = Asset.images([paImg+'okMedium.png',paImg+'cautionMedium.png',paImg+'blackWaiter.gif']);
                //comments are not closed ie 0 then only load.

               //   url = "http://nastroike.com/index.php?option=com_joocomments&random=" + Math.random();     
                document.id('comment-wrapper').set('html', '<img src="http://nastroike.com/components/com_joocomments/assets/img/spinner.gif" />Loading Comments...');                                  
                var req = new Request({
                     method: 'get',
                         url: tempUrl+"&random=" + Math.random(),                         
                         onComplete: function(text) { 
                        document.id('comment-wrapper').innerHTML = "" + text;   
                        loadTextEditor();                                                                                           
                        }                       
                    }).send();

                }); 
                        function loadTextEditor(){
                wmd_options.ajaxForm=true;   
                Attacklab.wmd();
                Attacklab.wmd_defaults={buttons:"bold italic link blockquote code image ol ul heading hr"};
                Attacklab.wmdBase();
                Attacklab.loadEnv();
                Attacklab.Util.startEditor();
                var myForm = document.id('myForm');
                myForm.action=tempUrl+"&task=postComment";
            // Labels over the inputs.
            myForm.getElements('[type=text], textarea').each(function(el){
                new OverText(el);
            });
            // Validation.
            var formValidator=new Form.Validator.Inline(myForm,{evaluateFieldsOnBlur:false,
                                                                evaluateFieldsOnChange:false,
                                                                onFormValidate:function(s,ele,on){
                                                                refreshCaptcha();
                                                                document.id('captchaText').value="";

                                                                if(sp!=null)sp.hide(true);                                      
                                                                }
                                                                }                                                               
                                                        );
                       formValidator.add('captchaValidator',{errorMsg:'Captcha is wrong.',
                                                      test:function(field){
                                                    return validateCaptcha(field);
                                                      }
                                                  }
                            );
            // Ajax (integrates with the validator).
            new Form.Request(myForm,null, {
                onComplete:function(){showComments();showEffect(arguments);refreshCaptcha();if(sp!=null)sp.hide(true);}
                ,async:false,
                requestOptions: {'spinnerTarget': 'progress'},
                extraData: {'article_id': article_id}
                });
                showComments();
            }            function showComments(){
                var parameter="&article_id="+article_id;
                var htmlRequest = new Request.HTML({url: tempUrl+'&task=showComments&view=commentpage'+parameter,
                    onRequest: function(){
                    document.id('comments').set('html', '<img src="http://nastroike.com/components/com_joocomments/assets/img/spinner.gif"/>Loading Comments...');
                },
                onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript){
                    document.id('comments').empty();
                    document.id('comments').innerHTML=responseHTML;

                     refreshCaptcha();              }}).send();
            }
                //]]>                       
                --></script>
<script
    src='http://nastroike.com/components/com_joocomments/assets/js/wmd.js'
    type='text/javascript'></script>
            <style>#wmd-button-bar #wmd-bold-button{left: 0px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-italic-button{left: 25px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-spacer1{left: 50px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-link-button{left: 75px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-quote-button{left: 100px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-code-button{left: 125px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-image-button{left: 150px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-spacer2{left: 175px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-olist-button{left: 200px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-ulist-button{left: 225px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-heading-button{left: 250px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-hr-button{left: 275px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-spacer3{left: 300px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-undo-button{left: 325px !important;}#wmd-button-bar #wmd-redo-button{left: 350px !important;}</style><center>Powered by <a href="http://www.bullraider.com" title="bullraider">Bullraider.com</a></center>

</div>

  </div>
```

Нужно убрать ссылку Bullraider.com

Вот адрес страницы, если нужно посмотреть исходный код: http://nastroike.com/tekhnika-i-instrumenty/142-vybiraem-kakoj-bojler-luchshe-kupit

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем проблема-то?

```
<center>Powered by <a href="http://www.bullraider.com" title="bullraider">Bullraider.com</a></center>
```

и переустанавливаем плагин.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/M8gOVIwyTJDZAhKYpzg

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. В исходном коде страницы этот код я, конечно, вижу, но дело в том, что компонент комментариев подключается к коду из внешних файлов, там целая папка, мне нужно найти, где.

Comment: Нашла нужный файл.